# Two MAX3140 (SPI to RS485) connected to one another

Tags: spi, rs485

I would like to ask if anyone had experience using this kind of IC, i had this school project where i have a lot of sensors using SPIs (each is 10-20 meters away from uC) and these needs to be somehow far from the main controller (uC). I knew that SPIs don't work well when implemented too far from the SPI master or SPI co-slave, so upon searching alternatives, i bump into some ideas like:

- use two uC and convert SPI to RS485 then convert RS485 to SPI
- use two uC and use their UART and convert them to RS485 then vice-versa
- use two uC and apply Ethernet/PoE between the two
- implement long distance SPI

i would like to re-consider the latter but i would like to try out first the former, then found this IC MAX3140, I'm totally new to this kind of data protocol connection when it comes to long distances. I have this image below where i want to use the IC in this kind of setup.

[image]

Did i get the gist of using these IC right?

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/controllers-expanders/MAX3140.html

i guess i do understand this structure below based on its datasheet

[image]

as you can see, there's only one Max3140 IC used and that'll only be (1) SPI to RS-485 alone. What i want to know if the below structure work out same since not specified on datasheet (using the IC vice-versa also, (2) RS-485 to SPI). Can it be the one way around? how about clock, etc?

[image]

Comment: Based on what you have, option 1 seems to be your only choice. Also if you use two of these per node you can use CAT-5 cable and RJ-45 connectors. Remember that RS-485 needs a signal ground to avoid DC drift.

Comment: Can you give an idea of how much 'somehow far' is? Reason: there is a well know saying *"Don't tell us the solution, tell us the problem"*. Also what bitrate do you need to read the sensors.

Comment: @Sparky256 thanks :D so you mean like ethernet/PoE, i should use CAT-5 wires to implement SPI-RS485 vice-versa?

Comment: @oldfart i'll edit the question for good reference, actually it'll be 10 to 20 meters aways, 10 meters away and additional 10 meters consideration for cable routing procedure.

Comment: Based on your last comment below, to monitor many sensors you need a multi-master or a polling scheme, with one master that constantly checks each sensor.

Comment: @Sparky256 yeah, that's why i use the SPI interface, but i as i go through, i have problem implementing this on longer distances that's why i want to know what could be the best addition to make this work like putting an adapter or repeater in layman's terms to propagate data transmission

Comment: Well RS-485 is your transmission and reception standard. The SPI is isolated from this, but you need to run a small ground wire from RS-485 port to port, so DC drift it not an issue. You will need to keep a SPI control stack in each port so they do not conflict, much like I2C does.

Comment: Please note that the top diagram with the two max3140s is incorrect and is not going to work because it shows two receivers at the bottom which are connected but there's nothing driving that bottom line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use two uC and convert SPI to RS485 then convert RS485 to SPI

Converting SPI to RS485 then back to SPI only really works in the master-to-slave forward direction. It doesn't work when trying to extract data from a slave because of the turn-around time and the immediate possibility that data coming back will gradually become out-of-sync with the forward going clock signal over longer and longer distances.

For instance I have sent 2 MHz clocked SPI converted to RS485 many tens of metres to drive remote DACs and it worked just fine - clock and data roll along to the slave and appear in-sync with each other and all is well.

> use two uC and use their UART and convert them to RS485 then
>   vice-versa

This is the obvious choice because you are creating a solution that does not require clock sync across the full cable - you have local sync at both ends and that works just fine. The MX chip appears suitable for this but, as always the devil is in the detail so read the data sheet to see if there are any gotchas.

> use two uC and apply Ethernet/PoE between the two

Harder to get up and running but could be the best overall solution for a "many-user" system

> implement long distance SPI

See my first answer - use 485 as a buffer and take note that slave-to-master comms will be problematic.

Comment: _It doesn't work when trying to extract data from a slave because of the turn-around time and the immediate possibility that data coming back will gradually become out-of-sync with the forward going clock signal over longer and longer distances._ Thanks a lot :D this is what makes me think also since i haven't use or had bought the IC, the data could be not properly propagated for the uC to compute. Actually, what i'm currently building is a DAQ system so yeah, sensors are about acquiring data and its vital for me.

Comment: @Mheruian if you are happy with this answer please consider accepting it. If you need more clarification then ask.

Answer (score 2):

There is LTC6820 (https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc6820.html) chip, that allows isolated long distance SPI over one twisted pair. The specs claim 1mbps, up to 100 meters.